# Angular 6: [(ngModel)] does not always work

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 6 and Bootstrap Modals to achieve below function, hit the modify button and a modal would pop up with values.

[image]

I use template driven form + [(ngModel)], however, it doesn't always work. Sometimes I can get full info, sometimes miss one or two fields, sometimes all fields are empty. (First time is good, but second time and after is all empty. Then if I click other info, the field is filled except the one's value is the same as last one)

[image]

[image]

My Code is as following:

1. Parent Component pass value to child component(modal)

```js
@ViewChild(ModBranchDialogComponent) modDialog : ModBranchDialogComponent;

(omit)

onModify(pKey: string){
    let bcnMain = this.branchDatas.find(x => x.pKey == pKey) as BranchMain;
    console.log('bcnMain=' + JSON.stringfiy(bcnMain));
    this.modDialog.showMod(bcnMain);
  }
```

2. model component(I can always print correct full info in this Console.log)

```js
export class ModBranchDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  public branchMain : BranchMain = new BranchMain();

  showMod(bchMain: BranchMain){
    console.log("modify bchMain=" + JSON.stringify(bchMain));
    this.branchMain = bchMain;
    $("#modBranchDialog").modal("show");
    $("#modBranchDialog").appendTo("body");
  }

}
```

3. modal HTML

```js
<div class="modal fade" id="modBranchDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modBranchLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:700px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form (ngSubmit)='doModBch()'>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div style="width:90%; margin:auto">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="branchId">branchId</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="branchId" name="branchId" [(ngModel)]="branchMain.branchId">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="branchCPS">branchCPS</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="branchCPS" name="branchCPS" [(ngModel)]="branchMain.branchCPS">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="branchNm">branchNm</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="branchNm" name="branchNm" [(ngModel)]="branchMain.branchNm">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="isSub">isSub</label>
                            <select id="isSub" class="form-control" name="isSub" [(ngModel)]="branchMain.isSub">
                                <option [ngValue]="" selected>-choose-</option>
                                <option [ngValue]="1">Y</option>
                                <option [ngValue]="0">N</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="belongBch">belongBch</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="belongBch" name="belongBch" [(ngModel)]="branchMain.belongBch">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">CONFIRM</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why sometimes it works, sometimes it not. Can anyone help? Thank you.

UPDATE: try add ngif as following, but no luck.

```js
branchMain: {{branchMain | json}}
      <form (ngSubmit)='doModBch()'>
        <div class="modal-body" *ngIf="branchMain">
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: A tangent observation: why would you use jQuery to directly manipulate the DOM? It's Angular, use `*ngIf` directive.

Comment: @mbojko Hi, can you be more specific on how to use ngif to show bootstrap modal? Thank you.

Comment: I think adding a Boolean variable, say, `isModalShown` to the component, and putting `*ngIf="isModalShown"` in the element you're manually jQuerying (so, `$("#modBranchDialog")`) should do the trick.

Comment: @mbojko Thank you very much, I got what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @angular/forms and ReactiveFormsModule, two-way binding usually very difficult for tracing and debugging. And I give you an advice - you should create and use small components for clean you code.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Where do you think I should change my code? I already have one parent component, and another component for dialog.

Comment: Switch to Reactive Forms, as @Ruslan already mentioned, Two-way can lead to these kind of bugs. Reactive Forms provide immutability of the Form's state over time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have asynchronous call, so try to avoid to render view until you have data through structural directive `*ngIf`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modBranchDialog" *ngIf="branchMain">
    ...
```

UPDATE:

Your `select` is not populated because `isSub` is not array. An example of populating `select`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="yourData"> 
    <option *ngFor="let item of yourData"> 
        {{ item }}
    </option>
</select>
```

TypeScript:

```
yourData = [1, 2, ,3 , 4 ,5]
```

UPDATE 1:

Try to add `?` sign like this to all your controls:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="branchNm" 
    name="branchNm" [(ngModel)]="branchMain?.branchNm">
```

UPDATE 2:

It seems to me really strange, but give a try to write `*ngIf` for all your controls:

```
<!--write *ngIf for all input's-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="branchId">branchId</label>
        <input 
             *ngIf="branchMain?.branchId"
             type="text" class="form-control" id="branchId" name="branchId" 
             [(ngModel)]="branchMain.branchId">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <label for="branchCPS">branchCPS</label>
        <input 
           *ngIf="branchMain?.branchCPS"
            type="text" class="form-control" id="branchCPS" name="branchCPS" 
              [(ngModel)]="branchMain.branchCPS">
         </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
         <label for="branchNm">branchNm</label>
         <input 
             *ngIf="branchMain?.branchNm"  
              type="text" class="form-control" id="branchNm" name="branchNm" 
              [(ngModel)]="branchMain.branchNm">
     </div>
</div>
<!-- and so on -->
```

UPDATE 3:

Try to clear your object with values and assign again:

```
showMod(bchMain: BranchMain){
    console.log("modify bchMain=" + JSON.stringify(bchMain));

    if (this.branchMain)
        this.branchMain = null;

    this.branchMain = bchMain;
    $("#modBranchDialog").modal("show");
    $("#modBranchDialog").appendTo("body");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Please see my update, I added ngif and also printed out the branchMain on the html, but it seems no luck.

Comment: However, not only isSub, sometimes all fields are empty, sometimes one or two text fields are empty, and sometimes isSub is empty.

Comment: @chloe try to create a sample object and see whether all controls are populated. It looks like sometimes your object returned from API does not have all values. Where is your code which gets data from API? Please, see my updated answer

Comment: Please check my last update, I added '{{branchMain | json}}' on the HTML, and it seems I got all the values but the fields are still empty.

Comment: Hi! I tried but still the same. I found out that first time click is good, all fields are filled, but second time and after is all empty. Then if I click other info, the field is filled except the one's value is the same as last one. So It seems that if values are the same, then fields are not filled......

Comment: After applying *ngIf, the controls are still all there, just no value. I also checked html, all the values are there but just not shown.

Comment: @chloe please, see my updated answer. What `changeDetection` do you use? https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef